# serialport communication .net 4.0 from a webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, serial-port

Looking for serial port communication using ASP.NET 4.0. I have a cardwriter/reader from IDTECH which talks through a comport. Is there any way to accomplish with .net through the web.

I read things but most of the topics on speaking about .net 2.0 and I was not sure if they created something to handle this in .net 4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything written for .net 2 should work in .net 4 with some changes that occur between revisions.  However, using the serial port from asp.net will not work on most servers as the user that the asp.net process is using won't have permission to access the hardware.

The only way around this would be to build the portion of the process that talks with the card reader/writer as a Windows service and add some method of communicating to the service from your asp.net application (TCP connection or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible is via a browser plugin.  This has nothing to do with .NET (unless that's what you use to write your browser plugin).

Everything you see about issues with the .NET serial port control are referring to desktop applications.  As a side note, most of the issues have been resolved in .NET 4.0, but not all.  I've given up and now use [CommStudio](http://www.componentsource.com/products/commstudio/downloads.html), which is available as an ActiveX control, so you may be able to access its methods from a web page.